# In Orbeon Forms, how can I upload CSS files in Form Builder?

Tags: orbeon

The [Persistence API docs](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-Virtual-hierarchy-of-data) says:

Each "form" collection contains:

- form.xhtml: the main form definition, which is an XHTML+XForms
- resource optional attachments, such as images, CSS, and PDF files
  uploaded by the form author when editing the form definition

This seems to indicate that Form Builder allows uploading CSS files for use in the form and that they would then be persisted in the database.

I have found several discussion threads on the Orbeon discussion forum that refer to an "Upload CSS" button, but I cannot see this button in the Form Builder menu. Has it been removed?

See discussion threads:
http://discuss.orbeon.com/Upload-CSS-Button-Click-Exception-td1692219.html
http://discuss.orbeon.com/location-of-form-builder-CSS-files-td37723.html
http://discuss.orbeon.com/Problems-using-Orbeon-Form-Builder-td42136.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that yes, this feature has been removed for 4.0. We didn't think it was quite the right way to do things, as in most cases the CSS should be per deployment or maybe per Form Runner app.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, the [Persistence API docs](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-Virtual-hierarchy-of-data) should be updated to remove mention of uploaded CSS as well as the style.css and logo.png. I think upload of a logo was also removed.

Comment: Thanks, I made changes to remove the reference to CSS and logo, and also to better reflect the format of ids and attachments (`.bin` extensions for example).